# How do you copy file paths quickly in Mac OS X v10.10 (Yosemite)?

Tags: macos, copy, filepath

Is there a quick way to copy file paths in [Mac OS X v10.10 (Yosemite)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Yosemite)?

Comment: You can also use the keyboard shortcut `cmd + option + c` and paste as normal.

To actually see the shortcut while in Finder, hold the `option` key and click on the `Edit` menu.

Answer (score 30):

1. Launch Automator (you can click the spotlight search feature in the upper right corner of your mac and search for Automator).
2. In Automator, click "New" in the "File" drop down menu (upper left hand corner of display screen).
3. Select "Service" for new file type (gear symbol).

-Now you can start building the shortcut-

4. Type the word "copy" into the search space on the right side of the automator program window (next to "Actions" and "Variables").
5. Drag "Copy to Clipboard" from the "search" area into the "workflow" area.
6. Change the "Service receives selected" drop down menu to "files or folders" (right above workflow area).
7. Change the "in" drop down menu to "Finder" (right above workflow area).
8. Save file as "Copy File Path."

[image: Automator screenshot for "Copy File Path"]

To use this "Copy File Path" command, when you are using Finder simply right click a file/folder and scroll down to the "Services" menu item at the bottom of the context window. Select the "Copy File Path" option and then paste wherever desired.

To access the Automator shortcut file for editing or renaming, click the "Go" drop down window when you are using "Finder" (near top of display). Next hold the "option" key and double click on "Library" (note that "Library" appears only after holding down "option"). Scroll down the Library folder until you find the "Services" folder. Open this folder and your new Automator shortcut will be inside.

Comment: Thank you! That worked for me

Comment: Nice, very helpful.